# Querying all tables of the databases for particular column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, unix

I need to find the particular column names of all the tables in the database which has the particular value.
I google it and got this query

```
select * from all_tab_columns where column_name='EXTERNAL_ID';
```

But this is not solved my requirements.
because in my case i dont know the column name,I know only the value stored in the column.

can you help me this?

Thanks.

Comment: Database is not just a text file to search in, so answering your question will put your DBMS in very high load with query time near infinity. Your DBA will not be glad if someone give you an answer. What is your final goal? Maybe this is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Even if you find some value in some column it will give you nearly nothing without knowledge of data model. And since you do not know column names, it is your case.

Answer (score 0):

The whole database? Huh, that's gonna take some time.

For simplicity, I searched only Scott's sample schema. Took columns whose datatype belongs to the *CHAR family* from `user_tab_columns` (you'd use `dba_tab_columns`), constructed dynamic SQL and performed search through all those columns for string `'SCOTT'`.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_search_string varchar2(20) := 'SCOTT';
  3    l_str           varchar2(200);
  4    l_tab_cnt       number := 0;
  5    l_cnt           number;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name
  8                  from user_tab_columns
  9                  where data_type in ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR2')
 10                 )
 11    loop
 12      l_tab_cnt := l_tab_cnt + 1;
 13      l_str := 'select count(*) ' ||
 14               '  from '  || cur_r.table_name  ||
 15               '  where ' || cur_r.column_name || ' = ' ||
 16               chr(39) || l_search_string || chr(39);
 17      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 18
 19      if l_cnt > 0 then
 20         dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||
 21                              ': ' || l_cnt || ' ocurrence(s)');
 22      end if;
 23    end loop;
 24    dbms_output.put_line('Search performed through ' || l_tab_cnt || ' table(s)');
 25  end;
 26  /
EMP.ENAME: 1 ocurrence(s)
Search performed through 64 table(s)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes ,its taking long time..
By the way my sincere thanks for you ji.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comment of @astentx, the database is just a couple of text files. I wouldn't do this on a daily basis, but you could search the datafiles with grep. This answer is obviously partly tongue-in-cheek, but nevertheless, searching for the value of 'Easter egg':

```
SELECT * FROM dba_data_files;

FILE_NAME                                FILE_ID  RELATIVE_FNO
/opt/oracle/oradata/ORA112E/users01.dbf        4             4         

cd /opt/oracle/oradata/ORA112E/
grep -abo 'Easter egg' users01.dbf
10216453:Easter egg
```

So we found it in the datafile at position 10216453. We need to divide this number by the blocksize of 8K, 10216453/8192 = 1247,12. This means, our row is in file=4, block=1247. We can find the table by looking up the extent:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dba_extents 
 WHERE file_id=4 
   AND 1247 BETWEEN block_id AND block_id + blocks;

ONWER SEGMENT_NAME SEGMENT_TYPE RELATIVE_FNO
SO    MYTABLE      TABLE                   4
```

So it's in the table `MYTABLE` in the schema `SO`. We need it's dataobject_id:

```
SELECT data_object_id FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE object_name='MYTABLE';  
100296
```

and can construct a rowid from the data_object_id, relative file number and blockid:

```
SELECT DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_CREATE (1, 100296, 4, 1247, 0) FROM DUAL;
AAAYfIAAEAAAATfAAA
```

With this rowid, we can find all rows in block 1247 very quickly and inspect the 68 rows:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM so.mytable t
 WHERE rowid LIKE 'AAAYfIAAEAAAATf%';

...
PUBLIC  /f5ed94fb_Base64Data1
SYS     /c609bc17_Base64Encoder
PUBLIC  Easter egg
SYS     /2dda5449_ByteArrayOutputStrea
...
```